# How to take a backup of data to a local machine from the AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I would like to have a copy of the Database in my local computer from the Amazon AWS RDS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can connect to the instance using any tool that does database dumps for the type of database you are running. For instance, [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) if you are have a MySQL or Aurora database.

If the database instance is not accessible to the internet you will need to make the dump from an EC2 instance that is in the correct subnet and security groups to talk to the database, or ssh tunnel through an instance to run mysqldump.

Note that RDS is configured by default to take daily snapshots of your database (which are stored in AWS, so you cannot download them), but you can restore from them if anything goes wrong. You can also take a manual snapshot at any time using the AWS web console or the API. You could also launch a new database from a snapshot and connect to it to create your local dump from a snapshot instead of the active database.